# Delayed Display of an Updated Element

Tags: html, button, display

I'm adding a spinner to a button when it is clicked in order to indicate to the user that some lengthy processing is occurring.

The problem is that the spinner does not get displayed until **after** the processing has completed, which, of course, defeats the purpose of the spinner.

How can I get the spinner to display **before** the start of the processing?

```js
function clicked() {
  document.getElementById("spinner").classList.add("fa", "fa-spinner", "fa-spin");
  // the for loops are to imitate my behind the scenes processing tasks.
  for (let i = 0; i <= 199999999; i++) {
    for (let j = 100000; j <= 1; j++) {}
  }
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = 'Done with the processing.';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="button" onclick="clicked();"><i id="spinner"></i>Submit</button>
  <p id="paragraph"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: consider creating a small delay with `setTimeout`, rather than trying to force it with an "enormous" loop (which blocks the thread)?

Comment: Make your function `async` (`async function clicked`) and instead of the loop, add `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000))` and you will see the spinner, as a promise timeout does not block the thread, as @DarkBee said.

Comment: DarkBee, I think you may have misunderstood. I wasn't trying to force anything with my loop. I was just trying to give an example of some lengthy processing. What is really happenning behind the scenes is some time-consuming database processing. But for purposes of this discussion, I wasn't going to post all that code.

Comment: somethinghere, your suggestion worked. Thank you.